# Is it true that we can wish or get whatever the soul desires in Jannah/Firdaus?

Tags: halal-haram, jannah

Can I be another race and be or wish to look a certain way. Like if I was Asian in Dunya can I be white in Jannah? Can you get a new and different family in Jannah if you ask Allah or wish for it? SO we basically get whatever we want as long as it isn't evil or sinful? Is this question permissible even?

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse...
The Almighty says in Holy Quran...
ولهم فيها ما اشتهت أنفسهم...
They will get there WHat they will desire...